# What does Approve button do with changeset on bitbucket.org?

Tags: bitbucket, changeset

When using Bitbucket for source control, there's an "Approve" button that appears at the upper right of the commit page:

[image: Bitbucket Approve Button]

It appears to generate an activity message in the repositories overview page:

[image]

Is that all it does? What is the intended purpose of that button? Is it just a social feature?

Comment: After googling for 2 hours I found that those buttons were called "Like" before [Redesign](http://blog.bitbucket.org/2012/10/09/introducing-the-redesigned-bitbucket/), and apparently they haven't changed description in some of their FAQs.

Comment: Also these button before redesign: http://blog.bitbucket.org/2012/06/28/pull-request-and-changeset-likes/ and approve changeset works as well?

Comment: @hellboy seems like that

Comment: This answer has some related information: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14609526/749232

Comment: The quick answer is yes, it's just a social feature. However changeset approvals are also exposed by the API and could theoretically be used externally, e.g. to enforce that all commits must be approved before merging to master, or a variety of other things.

Comment: This is the top result on Google for "bitbucket approve commit" and should be reopened or deleted. The comments have enough answer-type content that I am voting to reopen.

Comment: Original question was about "bitbucket.org". However, people might find this question when looking for information about "Bitbucket server" from "Atlassian". And on "Bitbucket server" one can configure the pull-request workflow to _depend on the number of approvals from other users_. In addition to reopening this question I suggest broadening it to include both "bitbucket.org" and "Bitbucket server".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One use case is when a pull request gets a certain number of approvals, then it gets merged, either automatically or manually.

Thus it becomes easy to filter all the pull requests which are ready to be merged.

It's quite a common feature in code review tools. I have found it to be almost identical in `GitLab` too.

Comment: Just for reference: GitLab was created two years after this question about bitbucket.org was posted.

Comment: I see. I didn't realize it when I answered it. At that time I just switched to GitLab from Bitbucket.

Answer (score 0):

The question was about commits, not pull request. I just created a new pull request from an approved commit and there was no automatic approval on the pull request from the same reviewer who approved the commit. Social feature indeed.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your post seems to be a basic description and commentary of the behavior you see when you click the Approve button, but it doesn't answer the question being asked or provide additional information discovered by your own research. Please see [How do I Write a Good Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for help writing constructive answers.