# Auto-approve commits in Bitbucket

Tags: bitbucket

I recently moved to the new Bitbucket interface and what I remarked is that I need to approve commits after pushing them.

It's a good feature, but it's inconvenient for my work-flow. Is there an option to disable it and have the commits automatically approved?

Edit: I uploaded an image of the Approve button.

[image]

Comment: I am on bitbucket and don't have to approve commits? You mean pull requests?

Comment: No, a simple git push origin master

Comment: Something weird going on there, done that a thousand times, no approval necessary.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

"Approve" is not necessary, is an extra feature to know who reviewed the commit. From Bibucket's blog [post](http://blog.bitbucket.org/2012/11/27/innovation-week-launches-several-new-features/):

> **Giving the green light**
>
> Bitbucket has a light-weight approval process that allows participants
>   to Approve a commit or pull request – this signifies that a user has
>   reviewed a change and that it [LGTM](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=LGTM).
>
> Later, when browsing the list of commits or pull requests, Bitbucket
>   displays the total number approvals for a particular change as a gray
>   circle.
>
> A gray badge shows how many reviewers have approved a particular
>   change – now, for those commits or pull requests that you personally
>   have approved, the badge is now green giving you a quick summary of
>   changes that are yet to be reviewed by you.

Comment: This answer is out of date unfortunately. I didn't investigate this behaviour but now, if I'm not approving my commits the changes would not be visible in the Source view.

Comment: I, too, would like to see this as optional or have a way to auto-click it. For our team's workflow, we don't look at other folks' pull requests until they have approved it themselves. Often, we will forget to approve our own pull requests, though, even though it is just one little click up in the corner.